# Permission Denied while using Shutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I am moving around files using the following script and am getting Permission Denied on random folders. This is a SharePoint site that is synced with my OneDrive and therefore on my File Explorer. A few of the files are working one step above in the folder structure, but this particular folder is not. I also can manually access the files just fine.

Any thoughts?

```
root_path = r'C:\Users\xyz\company'
downloads_path = r'C:\Users\xyz\Downloads'

# loop through each directory in the root directory
for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(root_path):
    # navigate to the "Key Process Workshops" folder if it exists
    if "Key Process Workshops" in dir_names:
        kp_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "Key Process Workshops")
        # loop through each PowerPoint file in the "Key Process Workshops" folder
        for file_name in os.listdir(kp_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(kp_path, file_name)
            # check if the length of the file path is greater than 255 characters
            if len(file_path) > 255:
                # create a copy of the file in the downloads folder
                new_file_path = os.path.join(downloads_path, file_name)
                #shutil.copyfile(file_path, new_file_path)
                #copy_file = os.path.basename(file_path)
                shutil.copyfile("\\\\?\\" + file_path, new_file_path)
                # update the file_path variable to use the copy
                file_path = new_file_path
            if file_path.endswith(".pptx"):
                # extract tables from each slide
                tables = []
                prs = pptx.Presentation(file_path)
                for slide in prs.slides:
                    tables += extract_tables(slide)
                # concatenate tables and add the result to the table_results list
                result = concatenate_tables(tables)
                if result:
                    table_results += result
```

Comment: WHERE do you get "permission denied"?  Don't make us guess.  Also remember that `os.listdir` returns the name of all files AND directories.  I don't think your code will handle a directory.  You shouldn't even need the `os.listdir`; the `os.walk` will eventually hand you all of the pptx files.  You can check the `dir_path` to see if it ends with your target.

Comment: @TimRoberts shutil.copyfile("\\\\?\\" + file_path, new_file_path) is where it's failing.

Comment: And that would certainly fail if `file_path` represents a folder.